# Are functions being recreated on each iteration?

Tags: reactjs

I wonder about which version is more efficient. Because on the second version I feel like I am recreating same component with same functions over and over again. But at the first version it is creating functions once and passing them to each components. So which one is more performant and why?

------------ First version ------------

Parent Component

```
export const Parent = () => {
  const handleSomething() {
    // calculating something
  }

  const handleSomething2() {
    // calculating something
  }

 const handleSomething3() {
    // calculating something
  }


  return (
   <>
    {
     new Array(10000).map(_ =>  
      <Child 
        handleSomething={handleSomething}
        handleSomething2={handleSomething2} 
        handleSomething3={handleSomething3} 
      />)
    }
   </>
  )
}
```

Child Component

```
export const Child = () => {
   return <div>Test</div>
}
```

------------ Second version -----------

Parent Component

```
export const Parent = () => {
  return (
 <> 
    {
     new Array(10000).map(_ =>  
        <Child />)
    }

  )
</>
}
```

Child Component

```
export const Child = () => {
   const handleSomething() {
     // calculating something
   }
    
   const handleSomething2() {
     // calculating something
   }
    
   const handleSomething3() {
     // calculating something
   }

   return <div>Test</div>
}
```

Comment: Functions aren't created per component, the code only ever exists once, and only the data for each child exist once per instance.

Comment: Is this because of webpack or something is related to javascript classes? Do you have any source to give information about it?

Answer (score 1):

With functional components, if you create a normal function in the component body, you will have a separate function for every single component in the app. (You'll also have a separate function for every single *render*.)

It's somewhat similar to how, with classes in standard JS, putting a property on the prototype results in the property existing *once*, but putting the property on the *instance itself* results in the property existing for however many instances you have - and, as a result, could be (very marginally) less efficient than having only a single property on the prototype.

So, for your case, defining the function in the parent will result in fewer functions in memory existing overall. That said, there are two caveats:

- In a real app, the "efficiency" of this sort of thing almost never matters - there are almost always better things to focus your effort on. Better to write clean, readable code, then come back and tweak things later if you find that they need it.
- Usually, where a function gets defined in React is important to take into consideration because that will determine when other components that use it as a prop re-render. In your case, you could improve your first version by memoizing (or using `useCallback`) for your methods defined in the parent component, so that way your `Child`s will have the same props every time they're rendered - or, at least, without their props changing *every* render. You could also memoize the rendered Childs.